# Sequence and Function

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $X=R$ with the usual metric and $M=[0,2]$. Define $I,T:M\to M$ by$$ T(x) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{4} & \text{if  $0\leq x\leq \frac{1}{2} $} \\
\frac{x}{2} & \text{ if $\frac{1}{2}\leq x\leq 2$ }
\end{cases}$$
and 
$$ I(x) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{2} & \text{if  $0\leq x\leq \frac{1}{2} $} \\
x & \text{ if $\frac{1}{2}\leq x\leq 2$ }
\end{cases}$$
Is it possible to find a sequence $\{x_n\}$ in $M$
 such that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}Ix_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}Tx_n=t \hspace{0.2cm}\text{for some}\hspace{0.2cm} t\in M.$$
If not, then give the brief explanation.

Comment: I believe one of the domain inequalities should be strict.

Comment: oh no its okay if you have $\frac{1}{4}$

Comment: sorry should $I$ also be $1/4$ and $x/2$?

Comment: No, We cannot change $I$ and $T$. I think that for these functions it is not possible to find such sequence but I am not sure. Please clarify this.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

1. Since $I$ and $T$ are continuous, what happens with convergent sequences?
2. Maybe $\{x_n\}$ is not a convergent sequence in $M$, but this is not
   a problem. Why? (Remember that $M$ is a closed and bounded interval).

Answer (score 0):

Currently, if we have A sequence $x_n$ in $M$, then we can conclude that $x_n\to x\in [0,1/2)$ or $x_n\to x\in [1/2,2]$, assume the prior,

then $Tx_n\to Tx=1/4$, and $Ix_n\to Ix=1/2$, so the results are not equal.

Assume the latter, then $Tx_n\to Tx=x/2$, and $Ix_n\to Ix=x$,

But in $[1/2,2]$, there are no values $x$ such that $x/2=x$, since this gives us $x=0$ which is not in $[1/2,2]$.

So there is no sequence s.t $\lim_{n\to\infty}Tx_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}Ix_n$

Comment: There may be a sequence $\{x_n\}$ in [0,\frac{1}{2}) which is not convergent. For example {0,\frac{1}{4}, 0, \frac{1}{4}, 0, .....}

Comment: but in that case, $\lim_{n\to\infty}Tx_n$, and $\lim_{n\to\infty}Ix_n$, would not be defined, so it would still not hold, I just assumed we would consider convergent sequences.

Comment: You can say limit will not equal but limit will exist because for such $\{x_n\}$, $\lim_{n\to\infty}Ix_n=\frac{1}{2}$ but$\lim_{n\to\infty}Tx_n=\frac{1}{4}$.

Comment: No, I do not believe so, because the sequence is taking different values, you need one input for the function, i.e. if we had $x_n=(0,1/4,0,1/4,...)$, we cannot evaluate this to decide if they are not equal.

Comment: Its fine sequence $\{x_n\}$ is taking different value but by the definition of functions the sequence $\{Tx_n\}={\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{4},......}$ and the sequence$\{Ix_n\}={\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2},......}$

Comment: indeed those sequences are different, and cannot be the same, but the limits are undefined, so we cannot compare them. (but yes by intuition we could say the limits (if they somehow did exist) would not be the same.